# How do I find the minimum and maximum using Integer.MAX_VALUE?

Tags: java, arrays, integer, max, min

I am confused and stuck on how to find the max and minimum of my code in the array. I have to use Integer.MAX_Value and Integer.MIN_Value.

```
public class AnnualFuelUseTester
{
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    int sMiles1, eMiles1, dist;
    double price , gallons, mpg, GPM;
    int counter = 0;
    int total;

    AnnualFuelUse[] annual = {new AnnualFuelUse(12700,12751,51,2.8),
                              new AnnualFuelUse(12802,12908,106,5.8),
                              new AnnualFuelUse(12908,13014,106,5.8)};

    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    for(int index = 0; index < annual.length; index++)
    {
        annual[index].calcDistance();

        annual[index].calcMPG();

        annual[index].calcTotal();
    }
    System.out.println(

    "Fill up  Start Miles  End Miles  Distance  Gallons Used   MPG   Price   Cost");
    for(int index = 0; index < annual.length; index++)
    {
        System.out.printf("   %d      %6d        %5d    %5d         %.2f      %.2f   %.2f   %.2f\n",
                index + 1,
                annual[index].getStart(),annual[index].getEnd(),
                annual[index].getDist(), annual[index].getGal(),
                annual[index].getMPG(),  annual[index].getPrice(),
                annual[index].getTotal());

    }
    System.out.println("Minimum: " + max);
}
}
```

And here my other class used together

```
public class AnnualFuelUse
{
private int sMiles1, eMiles1,dist;
private double price, gallons, mpg, total, GPM;

AnnualFuelUse(int s1, int e1, int distance, double gals)
{
    sMiles1 = s1;
    eMiles1 = e1;
    dist = distance;
    price = 1.83;
    gallons = gals;
}

public void calcDistance()
{
    dist = eMiles1 - sMiles1;
}

public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

 public void calcMPG()
{
    mpg = dist / gallons;
}

public int getStart()
{
    return sMiles1;
}

public int getEnd()
{
    return eMiles1;
}

public int getDist()
{
    return dist;
}

public double getMPG()
{
    return mpg;
}

public double getGal()
{
    return gallons;
}

public void calcTotal()
{
    total = 1.83 * gallons;
}

public double getTotal()
{
    return total;
}
}
```

I am asking for a brief run over on how to find the minimum and maximum is arrays. Especially specific numbers that are the same (e.g 51,106 is my distances)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid I have to guess what value you would like to minimize or maximize. So be it the distance, because you want to use an Integer value.

```
int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
for(int index = 0; index < annual.length; index++)
{
    annual[index].calcDistance();
    if (annual[index].getDist() < min) annual[index].getDist() = min;
    if (annual[index].getDist() > max) annual[index].getDist() = max;
    annual[index].calcMPG();

    annual[index].calcTotal();
    .... 

}
```

If you use a double value, be aware that Double.MIN_VALUE is the mnallest value a double could have. You would need -Double.MAX_VALUE instead.